# How to refactor this code?

Tags: c#, .net, refactoring

how can i refactor this code down to one method or something?

```
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_gridModel.Header))
                _gridModel.Header += ",";
            if (item != null)
                _gridModel.Header += item.Header;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_gridModel.Width))
                _gridModel.Width += ",";
            if (item != null)
                _gridModel.Width += item.Width;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_gridModel.Align))
                _gridModel.Align += ",";
            if (item != null)
                _gridModel.Align += item.Align;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_gridModel.Filter))
                _gridModel.Filter += ",";
            if (item != null)
                _gridModel.Filter += item.Filter;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_gridModel.Type))
                _gridModel.Type += ",";
            if (item != null)
                _gridModel.Type += item.Type;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_gridModel.Sort))
                _gridModel.Sort += ",";
            if (item != null)
                _gridModel.Sort += item.Sort;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you have .NET 3.5:

```
string Filter(string input, SomeType item, Func<SomeType, string> extract)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
    {
        if (item == null) return ",";
        else return "," + extract(item);
    }
}

_gridModel.Header += Filter(_gridModel.Header, item, i => i.Header);
_gridModel.Width += Filter(_gridModel.Width, item, i => i.Width);
_gridModel.Align += Filter(_gridModel.Align, item, i => i.Align);

// etc...
```

Comment: perfect! -- exactly what i as looking for

Comment: Depending on your usage, with so many appends, it may give you better performance to use StringBuilder

Comment: Oh yeah if it's in a loop it might make more sense to pass a stringbuilder around instead of concatenation.

Answer (score 15):

To start, **refactor** the logic into a function.

```
_gridModel.Header = AppendItem(_gridModel.Header, item == null ? null : item.Header);
_gridModel.Width = AppendItem(_gridModel.Width, item == null ? null : item.Width);
...
...

string AppendItem(string src, string item)
{
 if (! string.IsNullOrEmpty(src))
  src += ",";
 if (! string.IsNullOrEmpty(item))
  src += item;
 return src;
}
```

A good next step could be to use **reflection** and properties:

**Edit:** Fleshed out reflection solution, haven't actually debugged it yet though.

```
AppendProperties(_gridModel, item, "Header", "Width", "Align", ...)

void AppendProperty(object gridmodel, object item, params string[] propNames)
{
    foreach (string propName in propNames)
        AppendProperties(gridmodel, item, propName);
}

void AppendProperties(object gridmodel, object item, string propName)
{
    PropertyInfo piGrid = gridmodel.GetType().GetProperty(propName);
    if (piGrid != null && piGrid.PropertyType == typeof(string))
    {
        piGrid.SetValue(gridmodel, 
            piGrid.GetValue(gridmodel, null).ToString() + ",", null);
    }

    if (item == null) return;
    PropertyInfo piItem = item.GetType().GetProperty(propName);
    if (piItem != null)
    {
        piGrid.SetValue(gridmodel, 
            piGrid.GetValue(gridmodel, null).ToString() 
            + piItem.GetValue(item, null).ToString(), 
            null);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 close enough, I might use a (ref string src, ...) and not return the value.

Comment: Would be faster, but I tend to default to no side effects when possible.

Comment: AppendItem(_gridModel.Header, item.Header); <- NullReferenceException when calling item.Header

Comment: I like your first step, I think it is actually better then the accepted answer. However, the use of reflection and magic strings in this context is, in my opinion, overkill.

Comment: Freddy: added check for item is null when calling the function, thanks.